# SQL Query to return last value from a number of tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, greatest-n-per-group

I hope you might be able to help. I'm a novice at SQL so this one is starting to bug me.

Currently I am collecting data every day for a `Meter Name`. This data is currently being logged in a table with the columns `TimeStamp, Name, Value`. However I would like to create a query which will only return the most recent (last) value recorded against each `Name` in the table.

I've built this query so far but the `Top 1` syntax doesn't seem to be what I need.

```
SELECT Top 1 (DataLog.Timestamp), MeterTags.Name, DataLog.Value
FROM Meters
INNER JOIN MeterTags
ON Meters.MeterId = MeterTags.MeterId
INNER JOIN DataLog
ON MeterTags.MeterTagId = DataLog.MeterTagId
WHERE Meters.MeterTypeId = 8
GROUP By MeterTags.Name, DataLog.Timestamp
```

Any advice you could give would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Apologies, yes SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to give each record a rownumber (resetting to 0 for each `MeterTags.Name`) then just select the first for each name:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  DataLog.Timestamp, 
            MeterTags.Name, 
            DataLog.Value,
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MeterTags.Name 
                                        ORDER BY DataLog.TimeStamp DESC)
    FROM    Meters
            INNER JOIN MeterTags
                ON Meters.MeterId = MeterTags.MeterId
            INNER JOIN DataLog
                ON MeterTags.MeterTagId = DataLog.MeterTagId
    WHERE   Meters.MeterTypeId = 8
)
SELECT  CTE.Timestamp,
        CTE.Name,
        CTE.Value
FROM    CTE
WHERE   CTE.RowNumber = 1;
```

Another solution is to use the `TOP 1` inside an [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  DataLog.Timestamp, 
        MeterTags.Name, 
        DataLog.Value
FROM    Meters
        INNER JOIN MeterTags
            ON Meters.MeterId = MeterTags.MeterId
        CROSS APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 TimeStamp, Value
            FROM    DataLog
            WHERE   MeterTags.MeterTagId = DataLog.MeterTagId
            ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
        ) DataLog
WHERE   Meters.MeterTypeId = 8;
```

Comment: The timestamp is not being returned in the format yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss, SQL Server Management Studio is displaying the timestamp in this format. 
There is an important difference. A date is a date, and has no format, it is only when it comes to being displayed as text that it needs a format. 
I am a big advocate that **all** formatting should be done outside of SQL in the presentation layer. The database is for storing data the presentation layer is 
for presenting it.

Comment: You can do it in SQL using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, timestamp, 112)`, however when being sent to the application layer this is now a string and not a date, so you won't be able to manipulate it as a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select Timestamp,Name,Value
from 
(

SELECT (DataLog.Timestamp), MeterTags.Name, DataLog.Value,rownum,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
 (PARTITION BY MeterTags.Name ORDER BY DataLog.Timestamp desc) AS rownum FROM Meters
 INNER JOIN MeterTags
 ON Meters.MeterId = MeterTags.MeterId
 INNER JOIN DataLog
 ON MeterTags.MeterTagId = DataLog.MeterTagId
)data
   where rownum=1
```